# Vuejs dynamic import of components resulted bootstrap not loaded

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I impementing dynamic import of my components in my router in vuejs after when i load the page the bootstrap not loaded.

```
//.babelrc
"plugins": [
        "dynamic-import-webpack"
      ],

//.route.js
const myRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/admin, component: RouterViewComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '/', component:  () => import('../components/myComponent.vue'), name: 'my-component' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: did u found answer ?